# Appending multiple lines to the end of a particular line in Linux file

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have the following piece of an xml document which I'm trying to manipulate slightly. Thus far I've used "sed" to find and replace pieces of it, and its now close enough to what I need. It looks something like this so far

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>
<AIFMReportingInfo
  CreationDateAndTime="2014-12-08T00:00:00"
  Version="1.2"
  ReportingMemberState="GB"

xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=AIFMD_DATMAN_V1.2.xsd xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance>
```

All thats left to do is append everything from "CreationDateAndTime" onwards, to the end of the 2nd line, so the output should look something like this

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>
<AIFMReportingInfo CreationDateAndTime="2014-12-08T00:00:00" Version="1.2" ReportingMemberState="GB" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=AIFMD_DATMAN_V1.2.xsd xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance>
```

Including the space between each line I append on the second line. Is there a way of doing this using sed? Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
~$ sed '1!{:a;N;$!ba s/\n//g}' myfile
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>
<AIFMReportingInfo  CreationDateAndTime="2014-12-08T00:00:00"  Version="1.2"  ReportingMemberState="GB"xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=AIFMD_DATMAN_V1.2.xsd xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance>
```

Except for the first line (`1!`), append the line to the pattern space (`N`), and if not the end of the file (`$!`) branch to label a `ba`. At the end of the file, substitute every `\n` with nothing (`s/\n//g`).

Comment: Hi fredtantini, Thanks for the comment, that also gives the right output. As mentioned below i'm looking to save these changes to the file. I probably should have mentioned that in original post. I think if I add a -i to your sed it may just work.

Comment: This worked great,     sed -i '1!{:a;N;$!ba s/\n//g}' myfile. And I appreciate the explanation of your syntax. Very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is enough.

```
tr '\n' ' ' < File | sed -r 's/(encoding=UTF-8\?>)/&\n/g'
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat File
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>
<AIFMReportingInfo
  CreationDateAndTime="2014-12-08T00:00:00"
  Version="1.2"
  ReportingMemberState="GB"

xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=AIFMD_DATMAN_V1.2.xsd xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance>

$ tr '\n' ' ' < File | sed -r 's/(encoding=UTF-8\?>)/&\n/g'
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>
 <AIFMReportingInfo   CreationDateAndTime="2014-12-08T00:00:00"   Version="1.2"   ReportingMemberState="GB"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=AIFMD_DATMAN_V1.2.xsd xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance>
```

Comment: Hi A M D, thanks for the prompt reply. Yep, that definitely gives me the correct output alright. I want it to save them changes to the file itself as opposed to printing it out at the command line. I'm thinking I should use sed's "-i" option somewhere in the sed part of your answer?